# Issue in connecting Rails client to Node server

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails-4, socket.io

I have a chat application on Nodejs+Socket.io which is running on http://localhost:5001 and the other hand there is a rails application which is running on http://localhost:3000

**What i want to achieve ?**

1. Connect rails client to node server to talk to each other.

**What i did ?**

*Node server working properly*

Added in rails chat page.

```
<ul id="messages"></ul>

<form action="">
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off"/>
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
<script src="http://localhost:5001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5001');
    socket.on('connect', function (data) {
        console.log('connected!');
    });
</script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function () {
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    });

    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
</script>
```

**What is the issue ?**

The moment i am loading the page it is showing connected (*connected to Node server side also*) but just after the first page load port becomes 5001 to 3000 and obviously  404 for socket.io.

[image]

Comment: Can I ask why you're setting up these two backends to provide the same service on different ports running on the same local machine? Also, why  connect through a browser instead of making internal calls to each of the service's respective endpoints? What happens when you try to connect the node app using the an IP instead of localhost?

Comment: Actually i have multiple rails server so i can't integrate node inside rails, coz if i do so i am afraid that i can face some issue in syncing online users, so i just want to separate Chat app(Node) and will be using it's functionality through REST.
Why through browser ? asper my understanding after going through the guide on socket.io page to serve the realtime response from server to the client we have to add it. BTW i am totally new to Node and socket so if you have any better method will appreciate.

Comment: Yeah, from the sounds of it you do not need a seperate Ruby entity. If I'm understanding you correctly, the Chat app could be stand-alone and just consume the existing backend as needed, for examplel. Chat me if you'd like to discuss more.